# How to test Subject with jasmine marbles

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs, jasmine-marbles

Angular 6, Rxjs, Jest, Jasmine-marbles.

very common scenario: a component that searches for server-side items.
In the component, there are some controls that can change search critera, and I'd like to code in "reactive-style". So in the component code I have something like this:

```js
class SearchComponent  implements OnInit {
  public searchData: SearchData = {};
  public searchConditions$ = new Subject<SearchData>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

  public results$: Observable<ResultData> = this.searchConditions$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(this.compareProperties), // omissis but it works
    flatMap(searchData => this.searchService.search(searchData)),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  // search actions
  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchConditions$.next(this.searchData);
  }
  public onChangeProp1(prop1: string) {
    this.searchData = { ...this.searchData, prop1 };
    this.searchConditions$.next(this.searchData);
  }
  public onChangeProp2(prop2: string) {
    this.searchData = { ...this.searchData, prop2 };
    this.searchConditions$.next(this.searchData);
  }
}
```

That's, a `Subject` that fires search conditions each time something in the UI has changed.

Now I'd like to test that search service will be called only for distinct input.
I can do it "without marbles" in this way:

```js
test('when searchConditions$ come with equal events search service will not be called more than once', (done: any) => {
    service.search = jest.fn(() => of(TestData.results));
    component.results$.subscribe({
        complete: () => {
            expect(service.Search).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            done();
        }
    });

    component.searchConditions$.next(TestData.searchCriteria);
    component.searchConditions$.next(TestData.searchCriteria);
    component.searchConditions$.next(TestData.searchCriteria);
    component.searchConditions$.complete();
});
```

Now I'd like to convert this test using *jasmine marbles*, but I don't know how...

I'd like something like this:

```js
test('when searchConditions$ come with equal events search service will not be called more than once', (done: any) => {
    service.search = jest.fn(() => of(TestData.results));
    component.searchConditions$ = cold('--a--a|', { a : TestData.searchCriteria});
    const expected = cold('--b---|', { b : TestData.results});
    expect(component.results$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

Obviously, it doesn't work...

#### Update

somehow close...using a "test helper"

```js
test('when searchConditions$ comes with equal events search service will not be called more than once - marble version', () => {
    service.search = jest.fn(() => of(TestData.results));
    const stream   = cold('--a--a|', { a : TestData.searchCriteria});
    const expected = cold('--b---|', { b : TestData.results});
    stubSubject(component.searchConditions$, stream);
    expect(component.results$).toBeObservable(expected);
});


// test helpers
const stubSubject = (subject: Subject<any> , marbles: TestObservable) => {
    marbles.subscribe({
        next: (value: any) => subject.next(value),
        complete: () => subject.complete(),
        error: (e) => subject.error(e)
    });
};
```

Comment: FYI, you should be able to write `stream.subscribe(component.searchConditions$)`. You wrote "_somehow close_", was there something about your approach that didn't work?

Comment: nothing, it works fine, just a little different than I initially supposed

Answer (score 1):

The main goal in tests to mock dependencies and don't change anything inside of testing unit SearchComponent.

Therefore `stubSubject(component.searchConditions$, stream)` or `component.searchConditions$ = cold` is a bad practice.

Because we want to schedule emits in `searchConditions$` we need to have an internal scheduled stream and we can use `cold` or `hot` here too.

source data (sorry, I guessed some types)

```js
type SearchData = {
    prop?: string;
};
type ResultData = Array<string>;

@Injectable()
class SearchService {
    public search(term: SearchData): Observable<any> {
        return of();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    template: '',
})
class SearchComponent  implements OnInit {
    public searchData: SearchData = {};
    public searchConditions$ = new Subject<SearchData>();

    constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

    public results$: Observable<ResultData> = this.searchConditions$.pipe(
        distinctUntilKeyChanged('prop'),
        tap(console.log),
        flatMap(searchData => this.searchService.search(searchData)),
        shareReplay(1),
    );

    // search actions
    ngOnInit() {
        this.searchConditions$.next(this.searchData);
    }
    public onChangeProp1(prop1: string) {
        this.searchData = { ...this.searchData, prop: prop1 }; // I've changed it to prop
        this.searchConditions$.next(this.searchData);
    }
    public onChangeProp2(prop2: string) {
        this.searchData = { ...this.searchData, prop: prop2 }; // I've changed it to prop
        this.searchConditions$.next(this.searchData);
    }
}
```

and its test

```js
test('when searchConditions$ come with equal events search service will not be called more than once', () => {
    service.search = jest.fn(() => of(TestData.results));

    // our internal scheduler how we click our component.
    // the first delay `-` is important to allow `expect` to subscribe.
    cold('-a--a--b--b--a-|', {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
    }).pipe(
        tap(v => component.searchConditions$.next({prop: v})),
        // or like user does it
        // tap(v => component.onChangeProp1(v)),
        finalize(() => component.searchConditions$.complete()),
    ).subscribe();

    // adding our expectations.
    expect(component.results$).toBeObservable(cold('-r-----r-----r-|', {
        r: TestData.results,
    }));
});
```

Now we don't change our testing unit, only its dependencies (`service.search`).

Comment: > The main goal in tests to mock dependencies and don't change anything inside of testing unit SearchComponent.


good point, but the searchConditions$ is public so its not "inside" in both solutions (mine and yours) and that's the dirty part. In a clean solution that should be private or protected, and test simulating what the user does (from the template). But that it's kind a mechanical part, while the important test is the compare in the observable. So, maybe I'd prefer to extend component for testing purpose ad use protected observable as I did above